# ComputeBandStats extremely slow

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, gdal

When I try to use ComputeBandStats it takes extremely long time to finish. Is there any way to speed up the process?

Here is my code:

```
inIMG = gdal.Open(infile)
bandas = [inIMG.GetRasterBand(b+1) for b in range(3)]
print('hej1')
meanSD = [b.ComputeBandStats(1) for b in bandas]
print('hej2')
```

It prints out "hej1" pretty fast, but it only writes "hej2" after several hours. Therefore it seems that ComputeBandStats is the problem.

I tried it with no parameter (has worked at an earlier date) and with 1, but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

(I am using python 2.7 and gdal 1.11.3)

Comment: Is it possible that it is taking an extremely long time? have you tried breaking out the list comprehension into a simple `for` loop so you can monitor progress?

Comment: It actually finished after several hours. Is there any way to speed up the process?

Comment: Your best bet would probably be to multiprocess it, split the task into multiple smaller tasks. How big is the data you are working with? Also, if the img file is really big, try it with a smaller test case to see if the process speeds up.

Comment: What are you doing with `meanSD` after you calculate it? It might make sense to make it a generator instead of a list then you are not having all the overhead of processing all that data at that point in time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that ComputeStatistics is much faster than ComputeBandStats, so I'm using it instead. I don't know exactly what the difference is, but aside from the speed advantage, ComputeStatistics also ignores no-data values, which turned out to be a problem for ComputeBandStats. It also calculates min, max, mean and std, which I all needed anyways.

This is the change I made:

```
inIMG = gdal.Open(infile)
bandas = [inIMG.GetRasterBand(b+1) for b in range(3)]
print('hej1')
stats = [b.ComputeStatistics(False) for b in bandas]
print('hej2')
```